# setting up a custom shortcode for a login

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to set up my first shortcode and am running into an error "syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ';' or ','"

maybe I've just been looking at it too long. Any ideas?

````
function user_logged_in_function() {
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
  echo 'Welcome, logged in user. <a href="'.wp_logout_url().'">Click here to logout</a>.';
}else{
  echo 'Please login by <a href="'.wp_login_url().'">clicking here</a>.'
}
}
function register_shortcodes(){
   add_shortcode('user_logged_in', 'user_logged_in_function');
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');```
````

Comment: You need a `;` after 'clicking here' in your else clause

Answer (score 0):

Return the codes to display the shortcode inside the content.

```
function user_logged_in_function() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      return 'Welcome, logged in user. <a href="'.wp_logout_url().'">Click here to logout</a>.';
    }else{
      return 'Please login by <a href="'.wp_login_url().'">clicking here</a>.';
    }
  }
  function register_shortcodes(){
     add_shortcode('user_logged_in', 'user_logged_in_function');
  }
  add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
```